# Appium can not find any element

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I'm have on automation project(java, appium, android)
In this project, the elements are stored in the database.
I get elements from database and try to find it:

1) Locator search using findElements:

```
if (!elementPath.equals("")){
    List elementFound = driverCommands.findElements(By.xpath(elementPath));
        if (elementFound.size() == 0){
            return null;
        }
        return (AndroidElement) elementFound.get(0);
}
```

2) Locator search using findElement:

```
String elementPath = entity.getElementPath();
driverCommands.findElement(By.xpath(elementPath));
```

In both cases I get nothing. But if I add `sleep()` before usage findElemen(s) with a wait of at least 4 seconds, as shown in the example below, then the element will be found.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(4000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
if (!elementPath.equals("")){
    List elementFound = driverCommands.findElements(By.xpath((elementPath));
        if (elementFound.size() == 0){
            return null;
        }
        return (AndroidElement) elementFound.get(0);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use raw types! Do handle `InterruptedException` correctly (by reinterrupting the thread). Exceptions should never be ignored. (Printing a stack trace and doing nothing else is ignoring the exception.) Set an implicit wait in Appium so that your find instructions wait up to a timeout for their action.

Comment: use explicit wait , to wait for an element to exists.